# Feasibility of SSO with SameSite Lax cookies, only?

Tags: post, cookies, get, single-sign-on, samesite

## Background

I was toying with the aspect of implementing `SameSite` for my cookies today. I already had `HttpOnly` and `Secure` so I thought this probably wouldn't be a big deal.

## Why It Broke

Well, it turned out that lots of things broke once I implemented the setting. This occurred with both `SameSite=Lax` and `SameSite=Strict`. I did some research and found this was due to SSO being prone to breakage with SameSite settings of `Lax` or `Strict` (as opposed to `None`):

- [Upcoming Browser Behavior Changes: What Developers Need to Know](https://auth0.com/blog/browser-behavior-changes-what-developers-need-to-know/)
- [SameSite Cookie Attribute: What It Is And Why It Matters](https://adzerk.com/blog/chrome-samesite/)
- [Site compatibility-impacting changes coming to Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/site-impacting-changes)
- [Microsoft Warns SameSite Cookie Changes Could Break Some Apps](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2020/01/28/samesite-cookie-changes-break-apps.aspx)
- [Adventures in Single-Sign-On: SameSite Doomsday](https://charliedigital.com/2020/01/22/adventures-in-single-sign-on-samesite-doomsday/)
- [SameSite cookies explained](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/)

My primary browser (Iron 70) is based on Chromium 70, so I never before encountered the change rolled out to Chrome 80 users back in February, which supposedly defaulted cookies without `SameSite` values to `Lax`. I installed the latest Google Chrome Portable to check it out and interestingly it seems the feature is currently *not* (thankfully) defaulting to `SameSite=Lax` as it might have used to - my site only broke on there once I explicitly enabled the following header:

`Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;SameSite=Lax`

It seems this is because without an explicit `SameSite`, Chromium treats this is as ["LAX + POST w/ 2-minute rule"](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/AknSSyQTGYs/m/YKBxPCScCwAJ?pli=1) by default (and I was testing rapidly, so it was within 2 minutes).

Even with `Lax`, though, all my single-sign on is broken and my realtime chat doesn't work anymore - either using Websockets or XHR requests. When I try to do single-sign on, somehow I end up logged out of the main website, which also doesn't make much sense - basically, everything is messed up.

1. Is there any hope of getting XHR or Websockets to work again with `Lax`? I have chat up at `chat.example.com`, but I also allow access to it in a side panel on `sub.someotherdomain.org`. My guess is the answer here is **no**, and the only way to get around it would make a URL available on the same domain which Apache simply points to the same script behind the scenes. Annoying, but it *could* be done - but is there another way?
2. My bigger question is: is single-sign on inherently incompatible with `Lax` and `Strict`? I've not really found much in the way of this. All the articles seem to treat breaking SSO with `Lax` as inevitable, and there are even some diagrams that explain *why* it breaks, but does SSO have to be that way?

## Mainstream Workaround

Most sites say to do `SameSite=None` to get around this and force the old behavior in all user agents. Technically, this works, but I'm wondering if there's any way hope of ever being able to use `Lax` instead? How could this be made to work without having to succumb to `SameSite=None`?

Comment: _“Strict seems rather useless to me, because if a link to a page on your site gets posted on a forum, when people click on it, suddenly they're not logged in anymore”_ - I don’t think your understanding of Strict is correct here. MDN phrases it as, _“Cookies will only be sent in a first-party context and not be sent along with requests initiated by third party websites.”_ - opening a link in the top browing context is first-party, […]

Comment: […] and just clicking a link is not a request _initiated by_ the 3rd-party site either. (That would apply to requests for embedded resources like scripts, stylesheets, images, or background requests made via JS.)

Comment: @CBroe Ah, thanks for the clarification, although when I was testing, I did seem to notice that. I'll need to play with that a bit more, then. Regardless, it seems that CSS, XHR and WS is out with Strict, and maybe Lax, too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> **TL;DR - Yes, you *can* use `SameSite=Lax` (but not `SameSite=Strict`) and not break SSO!**

There are two big things to note about `SameSite` cookies:

- **Lax** prohibits cross-site requests using `POST`
- **Strict** also prohibits cross-site requests using `GET`

A helpful summary:
[image]

<sub>Source: https://www.wst.space/cookies-samesite-secure-httponly/</sub>

**Strict** simply would not work, because it prevents any kind of cross-site request from sending cookies, which makes SSO impossible entirely. `Strict` is not even a viable candidate.

That leaves us with `Lax` and `None` (which has been the default up until now, and is slowly being supplanted with `Lax`).

> 1. Is there any hope of getting XHR or Websockets to work again with `Lax`? I have chat up at `chat.example.com`, but I also allow access
>    to it in a side panel on `sub.someotherdomain.org`. My guess is the
>    answer here is **no**, and the only way to get around it would make a
>    URL available on the same domain which Apache simply points to the
>    same script behind the scenes. Annoying, but it *could* be done - but
>    is there another way?

**No**.

The best solution here is to rewrite the URLs behind the scenes so you don't need to maintain duplicate resources. Either rewriting the URL using Apache's `mod_rewrite` or simply doing an `include('path/to/file.php')` would be an easy solution. The *content* returned is going to be exactly the same - but if it requires `Lax` cookies to be sent, the browser must be sending them to a domain that is an ancestor of the current domain.

> 2. My bigger question is: is single-sign on inherently incompatible with `Lax` and `Strict`?

No, fortunately, not!

> I've not really found much in the way of
> this. All the articles seem to treat breaking SSO with `Lax` as
> inevitable, and there are even some diagrams that explain *why* it
> breaks, but does SSO have to be that way?

It ***is*** true that a lot of SSO pages *do* break with `SameSite=Lax` - but this failure is *not* inevitable - it's implementation-specific. Let's compare the original method with a revised method which is compatible with `SameSite=Lax` cookies.

#### Original SSO process (requires `SameSite=None`)

1. User navigates to `sub.example.org` - not currently logged in because no cookie is set on this site
2. Page detects not signed in and automatically redirects to a page for SSO on `example.com` - if the user is not authenticated there, it redirects back and gives a username/password prompt. If the user *is* authenticated, there, continue.
3. On `example.com`, read the user's session data and create a unique token for the SSO call. Dump the token into a database and POST back to the original site with the token that was inserted.
4. Back on `sub.example.org`, read the token that was POSTED and query the database for that token, and from that retrieve the user ID.
5. Set the user ID in a local session on `sub.example.org` - now the session works as expected, since `$_SESSION['mysession']` returns the same information on both `example.com` and `sub.example.org` (because the user ID never changes, technically these are duplicate cookies).

**This will break with `SameSite=Lax`**. Why? Because the original request to the authenticator is using a `POST` request - and this is to a foreign domain - and this is considered dangerous by both `SameSite=Lax` *and* `SameSite=Strict` - and cross-domain `POST`s won't have cookies sent to the destination. Thus, the cookies aren't available and the authenticator doesn't know what user is authenticated so it *can't* create the temporary token for that user before posting back. That's why this doesn't work.

However, the important thing to note here is that the `POST` request ***isn't sending any sensitive data*** (at least in the implementation described above). It's simply *asking* for authentication - it doesn't even have any sensitive data to send!

So, why are we `POST`ing in the first place? Recall that `SameSite=Lax` allows first-level `GET` navigation (`SameSite=Strict` does not). Thus, we can take advantage of this by simply using `GET` instead of `POST` for the **initial** redirect *only*.

### Workaround

> How could this be made to work without having to succumb to
> `SameSite=None`?

Here's how. Because `Lax` permits top-level `GET` but not `POST` (which is supposedly "dangerous"), use GET for the initial redirection instead of POST.

Paradoxically, `GET` is arguably less secure than `POST`, but the sensitive data (the token for user) is only sent on the final redirect back to the site requesting authentication - the initial redirect only says "Hey, I'm requesting authentication".

Here's [a brief excerpt](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/DEV/IdP+SameSite+Testing) which backs up this possibility, which concludes:

> In conclusion, the IdP **should continue** to function when its cookies
> are being defaulted to SameSite=Lax by browsers (currently tested on
> Chrome 78-81 and Firefox 72 with the same-site default flags set).
> Typically, we have only seen the IdP itself break when the JSESSIONID
> is set to SameSite 'Strict', which should not happen apart from when
> explicitly trying to set SameSite=None with older versions of Safari
> on MacOS <=10.14 and all WebKit browsers on iOS <=12
> (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=198181). However with regards
> to achieving single-sign-on you may see degraded operation, and the
> following possibilities occur:

The initial redirect requires using the cookie on the authorizing domain, whereas the domain requesting authorization isn't requesting a cookie - it's *setting* a cookie based on the `POST` to it. So this should work with `Lax` in theory since no cookies need to be available on the final `POST` request - only the initial one. The final `POST` redirect won't be able to have cookies sent on that request... but it *doesn't need to* - we're sending the token in the `POST` request itself, and setting the cookie based on that. Genius!

### Revised SSO Process

**Original SSO** - requires `SameSite=None`:

1. Requester `POST`s to auth provider
2. Auth provider receives cookies (which requires `None` or undefined `SameSite`) and creates temporary token
3. Auth provider redirects back to requester with token, which verifies it and creates session cookie

**Revised SSO** - compatible with `SameSite=Lax`:

1. Requester `GET`s to auth provider
2. Auth provider receives cookies (because this is a `GET` now, not a `POST`) and creates temporary token
3. Auth provider redirects back to requester with token, which verifies it and creates session cookie

One difference — that's it - `GET` on the initial redirect, not `POST`. This works because the initial redirect contains no sensitive information. This `POST` could well have been a `GET`. By making it one, we can bump up the security level for the entire session cookie, and any Remember Me cookies - not bad!

I've tested this in both Chromium 70 and Chrome 84 with the strict flags and third-party cookies blocked (so no "Lax + POST", it's just "Lax"). This does work. You can also set any Remember Me cookies to `SameSite=Lax` as well - if the authenticator needs to use them to create a session spontaneously because no session was ongoing, the cookies to do so will be available as long as the redirect there was a `GET` and not a `POST` - so we're good!

#### Conclusion

SSO *can* work with `Lax`. Obviously, XHR, dynamic CSS, websockets, etc. will not, but those could be trivially proxied behind the original domain. By utilizing `GET` instead of `POST` on the initial redirect, you can move to using cookies with `SameSite=Lax`.

More complex SSO processes might be different - what I've given here is just a very simple SSO example. However, SSO and `SameSite=Lax` are *not* mutually incompatible - you can make it work by slightly tweaking your SSO setup, and if you make other changes as needed, nothing will break.

Note that you *can* still do sessions with `SameSite=Strict` - and if your entire site is on a single hostname and it's highly sensitive, I'd recommend that instead. But, if you need to do SSO, you can at least use `SameSite=Lax` (but not `Strict`, of course).